# Drop Shadow Design in AI CS5 with linked PSD Image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, drop-shadow

I am doing a ring of products with drop shadow, but I am unable to get a unify shadow direction.

I know one way to solve this will be do it all in Photoshop, and place the circle back to AI, but already design mutiple ring of products and designs I don't want to go back and redo it all.  is there a way to achieve this in AI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CC the shadows rotate, so if upgrading isn't an option and you need to keep the link I would suggest manually editing each shadow.

[image]

And then creating a graphic style for each "position" of the chips to quickly apply it to new linked groups.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the shadows **after** you've arranged the bags in a circle, not before.

- Arrange objects in a circle
- Select all of your objects and go to Effects > Stylize > Drop Shadow

[image]

[image]